# how to retrieve array data at jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to call a codeigniter controller function from ajax jquery function, and on success i am getting the result in array form. I need to output the array values into different text fields. how can i retrieve the array values with jquery ajax. My code,

```
<?php 
 echo form_open(base_url().'index.php/tapal');  ?>
    <table class="register-table">
    <tr>
                    <td>Tapal No.</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="tapal_no" name="Tyear" id="Tyear" placeholder="<?php echo date('Y');?>" />
                        <input type="text" class="tapal_no" name="Tno" id="Tno" />
                        <input type="text" class="tapal_no" name="Tdist" id="Tdist" placeholder="7" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td><label for="T_sender">Sender Code<span class="required_field">*</span></label></td>
                    <td><select id="T_sender" name="T_sender">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php if(isset($Tsender)) : foreach($Tsender as $send) : ?>
                            <?php echo "<option value=".$send->add_id.">".$send->add_name.",&nbsp;".$send->add_line1."</option>"; ?>    
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php else : ?> 
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </select> 
                    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sender Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="text-input" name="send_name" id="send_name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Address</td>
        <td rowspan="3"><div><input type="text" class="text-input" name="add_line1" id="add_line1" placeholder="Building Name/ No." /></div>
                        <div><input type="text" class="text-input" name="add_line2" id="add_line2" placeholder="Street/ Lane" /> </div>
                        <div><input type="text" class="text-input" name="add_line3" id="add_line3" placeholder="City/ Dist" /> </div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php    echo form_close();     ?>
```

And the jquery function ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#T_sender").change(function(){   
        var sender_code = $(this).val();            
        var out = $("#send_name");
        var ajax_data = {
            sender_code:sender_code,
            action:'findaddress'
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('tapal/tapalajaxqry'); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: ajax_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#send_name").val(msg);       
            }
        });
});
})
</script>
```

And the controller function,

```
    function tapalajaxqry()
{
    if(strncmp($this->input->post('action'),'findaddress',11) == 0){
        if($query = $this->tapal_model->get_Taddress($this->input->post('sender_code')))
        return $query;
    }
}
```

How can i get the array values,and output them (sender name,address line1,address line2,etc) into corresponding text fields?

Comment: You can return a json object with the function `json_encode` and parse it in jQuery and work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to encode the output as JSON ([`json_encode($array);`](https://www.php.net/json_encode)) so that you can easily retrieve and decode the result with your ajax/jquery with [`JSON.parse(data);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript).

There are countless similar posts on the subject, though since yours is unique to your code, it doesn't need to be flagged as a duplicate.

Try this for starters, respond with a comment if you need further assistance: [Retrieving Data from a database in codeigniter using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641443/retrieving-data-from-a-database-in-codeigniter-using-ajax?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In your controller

```
function tapalajaxqry()
{
    // Your code here


    // respond to jQuery
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
}
```

In your jQuery code, would retrieve like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('tapal/tapalajaxqry'); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: ajax_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#send_name").val(msg.result);       
            }
});
```